# angular moment pipe 'amDifference' could not be found

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-moment

I am trying to run the `amDifference` calculation on 2 dates from:
https://github.com/urish/angular-moment#amdifference-filter

The error I get:

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
The pipe 'amDifference' could not be found ("yling">{{i['Date']}}</td>-->
                                    <td class="date-font-styling">{{[ERROR ->]formatted_date | amDifference : i['Date'] : 'days'}}</td>
                                    </tr"): ng:///LayoutModule/AboutComponent.html@213:68
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:485)
    at TemplateParser.parse (compiler.js:24668)
    at JitCompiler._parseTemplate (compiler.js:346
```

What I'm trying to do:

In my `component.ts` I have defined a variable for the local current time formatted in date/time format: `YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS`. On the front HTML side, I have a button that calls a function in the `component.ts` which returns a JSON object from my API containing a date, also formatted in the same date/time format. I want to subtract the current local time (as defined in the component formatted_date , against what I am returning from the JSON data).

My code for this in the HTML (based on what that website said to do):

```
<div *ngFor="let i of json">
<span>{{formatted_date | amDifference : i['Date'] : 'days'}}</span>
<div>
```

To install the `angular-moment` module, I have run the `npm install angular-moment` and imported into my component.ts using: `import * as moment from 'moment';`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use angularjs library with angular. The above library currently supports only angularjs versions.

And it's a filter you're trying to use a s a pipe. I would suggest you to use  **[`angular2-moment`](http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular2-moment)**

try `import {MomentModule} from 'angular2-moment/moment.module';`

after

```
npm install angular2-moment
```

Comment: do you have any suggestions for datetime comparisons

Comment: can you update the link. Also, i am using angular 5 typescript

Comment: updated above , i think that should support angular5 aswell